# .java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: java, android, gradle, compilation, warnings

I am new to Android. I started a new Project and implemented a Intro Navigation and App Drawer Screens. When I published "APK", intro sliders are working fine and "Side Bar Menu" app drawer is not working and app crashes,.

Gradle console has a warning message:

> Note:
>   E:\AndroidApps\GoTogether\app\src\main\java\com\softvision\gotogether\app\WelcomeActivity.java
>   uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details.

How to Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation in Android Studio?

Here's my code:

```
package com.softvision.gotogether.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Shreekumar S [shreekumar.s@softvision.com] on 20-11-2017.
 */

public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PreferenceManager _preferences;
    private ViewPager _viewPager;
    private LinearLayout _linearDotsLayout;
    private Button _btnSkip, _btnNext;
    private int[] _slideLayouts;
    private TextView[] _textViewDots;

    private WelcomeViewPagerAdapter _welcomeViewPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Checking for first time launch - before calling setContentView()
        _preferences = new PreferenceManager(this);
        if (!_preferences.IsFirstTimeLaunch()) {
            LaunchHomeScreen();
            finish();
        }

        // Making notification bar transparent
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        // get controls of Welcome screen
        _viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.welcomeViewPager);
        _linearDotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.welcomeLinearLayout);
        _btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSkip);
        _btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

        // layouts of all welcome sliders
        // add few more layouts if you want
        _slideLayouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.intro_slide_1,
                R.layout.intro_slide_2,
                R.layout.intro_slide_3,
                R.layout.intro_slide_4};

        // adding bottom dots
        AddBottomDots(0);

        // making notification bar transparent
        ChangeStatusBarColor();

        _welcomeViewPagerAdapter = new WelcomeViewPagerAdapter();
        _viewPager.setAdapter(_welcomeViewPagerAdapter);
        _viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(onPageChangeListener);

        // On Skip button Click
        _btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LaunchHomeScreen();
            }
        });

        // On Next button Click
        _btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // checking for last page
                // if last page home screen will be launched
                int current = GetItem(+1);
                if (current < _slideLayouts.length) {
                    // move to next screen
                    _viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
                } else {
                    LaunchHomeScreen();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void LaunchHomeScreen() {
        _preferences.SetFirstTimeLaunch(false);

        // Move from Welcome Activity to Main Activity
        startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

        finish();
    }

    private void AddBottomDots(int currentPage) {
        _textViewDots = new TextView[_slideLayouts.length];

        int[] colorsActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_active);
        int[] colorsInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_inactive);

        _linearDotsLayout.removeAllViews();

        for (int i = 0; i < _textViewDots.length; i++) {
            _textViewDots[i] = new TextView(this);
            _textViewDots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
            _textViewDots[i].setTextSize(35);
            _textViewDots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[currentPage]);
            _linearDotsLayout.addView(_textViewDots[i]);
        }

        if (_textViewDots.length > 0)
            _textViewDots[currentPage].setTextColor(colorsActive[currentPage]);
    }

    // Making notification bar transparent
    private void ChangeStatusBarColor() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }

    private int GetItem(int i) {
        return _viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }

    // View pager adapter
    public class WelcomeViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public WelcomeViewPagerAdapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(_slideLayouts[position], container, false);
            container.addView(view);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return _slideLayouts.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return view == obj;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            View view = (View) object;
            container.removeView(view);
        }
    }

    //  ViewPager change listener
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener onPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            AddBottomDots(position);

            // changing the next button text 'NEXT' / 'GOT IT'
            if (position == _slideLayouts.length - 1) {
                // last page. make button text to GOT IT
                _btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.start));
                _btnSkip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                // still pages are left
                _btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.next));
                _btnSkip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Question of style "why isn't this code working" are offtopic on SO, please read log files and attach a debugger to find out why your code is misbehaving. More info also at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. The warning just means that you use stuff that you shouldn't use anymore and that will be removed in some later version, it should not cause the crash. Actually Android Studio should also show you those usages by striking through the deprecated usage.

Comment: How to Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation?

Comment: To enable it in all java compilation tasks in all projects do in the root build file `allprojects { tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { options.deprecation = true } }`, or just set the option on selected tasks.

Comment: In whcih file i need to set this?

Comment: As I said, in the root build script

Comment: build.gradle of the app module

Answer (score 0):

```
Html.fromHtml("&#8226;") //It is deprecated.
```

Refrance: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)

Solution:

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml("&#8226;", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
```